# Accessing URL helpers in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to redirect a path in routes using the following lines:

```
get 'privacy_policy', :controller => :pages, :as => 'privacy_policy'
get 'privacypolicy.php' => redirect(privacy_policy_url)
```

So that /privacypolicy.php gets redirected to the correct page defined right above it.

However, it's throwing the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `privacy_policy_url'
```

So I'm guessing one cannot use URL helpers in routes.rb. Is there a way to use URL helpers in the route file, and is it advisable to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know I'm a little late here, but this question is one of the top hits when googling "use url_helpers in routes.rb", and I initially found it when I had stumbled upon this problem, so I'd like to share my solution.

As @martinjlowm mentioned in his answer, one cannot use URL helpers when *drawing* new routes. However, there *is* one way to define a redirecting route rule using URL helpers. The thing is, [ActionDispatch::Routing::Redirection#redirect](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html#method-i-redirect) can take a block (or a `#call`-able), which is *later* (when the user hits the route) invoked with two parameters, **params** and **request**, to return a new route, a string. And because the routes are properly drawn at that moment, it is completely valid to call URL helpers inside the block!

```
get 'privacypolicy.php', to: redirect { |_params, _request|
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.privacy_policy_path
}
```

Furthermore, we can employ Ruby metaprogramming facilities to add some sugar:

```
class UrlHelpersRedirector
  def self.method_missing(method, *args, **kwargs) # rubocop:disable Style/MethodMissing
    new(method, args, kwargs)
  end

  def initialize(url_helper, args, kwargs)
    @url_helper = url_helper
    @args = args
    @kwargs = kwargs
  end

  def call(_params, _request)
    url_helpers.public_send(@url_helper, *@args, **@kwargs)
  end

  private

  def url_helpers
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end

# ...

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'privacypolicy.php', to: redirect(UrlHelperRedirector.privacy_policy_path)    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

URL Helpers are created from the routes. Therefore they won't be usable when drawing new routes.

You will have to use gayavat's approach.

-- or --

Redirect using the exact URL like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html does.

edit:

If it's more than just the one '...php' route, you might want to consider making a redirect controller. Take a look here, how to se it up: http://palexander.posterous.com/provide-valid-301-redirects-using-rails-route

Inside your routes file, you should add this at the bottom, so it doesn't interfere with other routes:

```
get '/:url' => 'redirect#index'
```

Comment: That makes sense. I've seen the exact URL approach, but I don't want to rewrite the path twice if I decide to move a page. It's however the best solution so far, if the helper falls through (I don't want to create a new variable per page to contain the path).

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm afraid, there is no easier way to do this. If it's not just the one '...php' route you want to redirect, you can take a look at the link I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
get 'privacypolicy.php' => "privacy_policy#show"
```

Comment: That's not a redirect however, which is what I want. I need it to send a 302 code.

Comment: you may return 302 as http status: http://blog.futureshock-ed.com/http-status-code-symbols-for-rails

render <template>, :status => :found

Comment: it would require a method in the controller though.