# setting an app's root to a route in an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to set my application's root to an action of an engine's controller. I thought this in my `config/routes.rb` would get it done:

```
root action: :show, controller: :pages, module: :MyEngine
```

But I'm getting a `uninitialized constant PagesController` error. Are the routes being set before the engine's controllers are being auto loaded?

Comment: did you try mounting your engine to the main app inside config/routes.rb:  
`mount Myengine::Engine => "/myengine", :as => "myengine"`

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. Those routes are working correctly. I'm trying to add an additional route in my app to one of the engine's controllers.

Comment: Have you tried setting `module` to `:my_engine` or `'my_engine'`?  The documentation seems to imply that the `module` option expects snake_case.

Comment: Ya, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explicitly declared the controller I was using without the name spacing in `config/routes.rb`.

```
PagesController = MyEngine::PagesController

root action: :show, controller: :pages
```

That did it. I'm wondering if I found a bug with the `module` option?

Comment: That works, but I probably wouldn't do it this way.  Now that I think about it, have you tried setting the controller option to `"MyEngine::PagesController"`?

Comment: I get "not a supported controller name."

Answer (score 4):

The engine's controllers won't be loaded until after it's mounted, I believe.  I couldn't find a way to route to an engine the way you want, but I did find these ways:

1) Mount the engine at root (probably not strictly what you wanted)

```
mount MyEngine => '/', as: :myengine
```

2) Redirect root to the engine

```
# For redirecting to the engine's mount
root to: redirect { Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.myengine_path }

# For a specific engine path
root to: redirect { MyEngine.routes.url_helpers.some_path }
```

If you don't mind hard-coding your engine path, you can just:

```
root to: '/myengine/url'
```

There probably exists a better way of handling these helpers in the routes, but this was the most direct way I could find.  I did stumble across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39761089/1772133) on a slightly related question that mentions creating a helper specifically for this kind of thing.  Adapting it for use with an engine might give something like:

```
class UrlRedirectHelper

  # This makes the case where you just want to use the main app's routes less verbose
  def self.method_missing(method, *args, **kwargs)
    new.public_send(method, *args, **kwargs)
  end

  # This is some entirely unnecessary sugar, I just like the way it reads
  def self.for(engine)
    new(engine)
  end

  def initialize(engine = Rails.application)
    @engine = engine
  end

  # This is called by `redirect` when it's preparing to redirect the user
  def call(_params, _request)
    url_helpers.public_send(@method, *@args, **@kwargs)
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, **kwargs)
    super unless url_helpers.respond_to? method

    @method = method
    @args = args
    @kwargs = kwargs

    self
  end

  private

  # you could also `delegate` this, but it keeps the API cleaner to make it private
  def url_helpers
    @engine.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

Which is then used like so:

```
get :somepath, to: redirect(UrlRedirectHelper.some_other_path)

# or, for an engine
get :somepath, to: redirect(UrlRedirectHelper.for(MyEngine).some_other_path)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I started messing around with the redirects but then thought "what happens when I declare the controller explicitly". That worked. It's as is the `module` option isn't working.